# Flask access json data and embedding it in a <img> tag

Tags: python, html, flask, web

I have the following flask route

```py
@app.route("/rec_demo")
def rec_demo():
    print("de lokos")
    response_data = {"rec_one": "pic_trulli.jpg"}

    return render_template("demografico.html", data=response_data)
```

And I try to access the rec_one to display it as an image

```html
<div id='info_section'>
        <img src={{ data.rec_one }} alt="Girl in a jacket" width="500" height="600">
</div>
```

But when I check the web on a live server the src doesn't resolve to the url I passed. If instead I had

```html
<div id='info_section'>
        {{ data.rec_one }}
</div>
```

I can see the url value as text in my webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be putting quotes around your `flask` call --  IE

```
<img src="{{ data.rec_one }}" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="500" height="600">
```

This will cause problems not only with the `flask` output .. But the browser's interpretation as well.